# Configuring white labeling between sendgrid and 1and1.com

Tags: 1and1, sendgrid

I'm struggling to configure white labeling between sendgrid and 1and1.com.

Sendgrid asks me to create a variety of subdomains on my domain registrar with specific CNAME values. I'm able to create most of them but I was stuck on:

```
s1._domainkey.<mydomain>
```

1and1.com is giving me an "invalid subdomain error. The subdomain could not be created. An error has occurred" Anyone else come across this and resolved it? Do I need to switch registrars?

I can create the subdomain without the underscore but then it doesn't validate against sendgrid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got this question answered by SendGrid's support team. Pasting their response here:

> If I recall, 1 & 1 doesn't support the _ value in the CNAME record.
>
> What you can do is create a TXT record instead.
>
> Head over to your SendGrid account -> Select Settings -> Whitelabel.
>
> Delete your old whitelabel and add a new one using the same subdomain and domain ' mail.'. This time, **Turn off the automated security box** so we use TXT records vs. CNAME records for your DKIM config.

Back on 1and1.com's configuration screen I was able to create the TXT records as spec'd by SendGrid.

Comment: I have tried this solution and it looks that now for TXT they generate a subdomain like this: `m1._domainkey....` so they are using underscore here too. Maybe they changed since your answer.

Answer (score 1):

1&1 does not allow underscores in their DNS Records, or at least in their CNAME DNS Records, despite underscores being allow in the RFC.
I can't find documentation from them on it, but it's a problem I've heard of many times in the past; you might want to contact their support to confirm.